# How to access resolver fields from other resolver fields in graphql?

Tags: graphql

Pretty sure this question has been asked, but I feel like the examples and solutions are not very good. Basically I want to know how to do this.

schema:

```
type Person {
  first: String!
  last: String!
  full: String
  greet: String
}
```

resolvers

```
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    Person: {
      full: ({ first, last }) => first + ' ' + last,
      greet: ({ full }) => `Hello, my name is ${full}`
    }
  }
}
```

Is it possible to access other resolver fields in other resolvers without crazy workarounds [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41597148/graphql-accessing-another-resolver-field-output-from-a-sibling-resolver)?