# Apollo server throw multiple errors with partial data

Tags: angular, error-handling, graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have implemented graphql apollo server with query:

```
ordersSearch{
  name
  orders: {
    id
    name
  }
}
```

For orders for which data isn't present I want to throw array of not found errors with data for orders with data like below:

```
   {
    "errors": [{
      "message": "404: Not Found", 
      "path": [ "ordersSearch", 0, "order", 1 ], 
      "extensions": { … }
    }, 
    {
      "message": "404: Not Found", 
      "path": [ "ordersSearch", 0, "order", 3 ], 
      "extensions": { … }
    }],
    "data": “ordersSearch”: [ 
      "name": “test”, 
      "orders": [ {
        “id": “2”,
        name: “test”
    }]
  }
```

In above response data not found for orders #1 and #3 and found for order#2.

How to implement this in apollo server. Currently, if I throw an error the query execution stops and one error is returned with `data` property as `null` as below:

```
{
  "errors": [{
    "message": "404: Not Found", 
    "path": [ "ordersSearch", 0, "order", 1 ], 
    "extensions": { … }
  }],
  "data": null
}
```

Comment: Maybe I'm focusing to closely on the example, rather than the principle being asked about, but this feels very much like REST to me, and not GraphQL. Is there any reason you wouldn't just return `null`? That's "not found" in GraphQL speak.

Comment: We want a way to let client that some orders aren't found. Also, there might be other errors in other schema prop which we want to catch and send with partial data.

Comment: In this case, the `null` is how you tell the client that some orders aren't found `orders: [ {...}, null, null, {...}]`.

Comment: We want to let user know which order Ids aren’t found. Not possible if we send null

Comment: 2 ways: 1. all of the orders have an `id` on them. The client could _check_. 2. Return them in the same order as in the request.

Comment: @DanCrews order ids are not known to the client beforehand hence it won't work. I can't change the schema setup so lets talk about the actual problem.

Comment: it looks like artificial problem to cover bad DB design ... work on DB **consistency** instead

Comment: @xadm agreed. But can’t change the datasource am fetching data from. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

There are two broad solutions to consider, but we need to know more about your graphql schema.

I assume that your schema is the following:

```
type query {
  ordersSearch: OrdersSearch!
}
type OrdersSearch {
  name: String!
  orders: [Order!]!
}
type Order {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
```

## 1. With minimal changes to your schema

Which fields are marked as non-nullable in your schema is very important here.
This is the part of your message that makes me assume your schema has too many "`!`".

> if I throw an error the query execution stops and one error is returned with data property as null

As per the GraphQL [spec here](http://spec.graphql.org/June2018/#sec-Errors):

> If the field which experienced an error was declared as Non-Null, the null result will bubble up to the next nullable field. In that case, the path for the error should include the full path to the result field where the error occurred, even if that field is not present in the response.

So if your resolver for an `Order.name` field throws an error, your GraphQL server can't just return a null `name`. It cannot either return a null `Order`. If you're using the default resolver for the `orders` array, it will not skip this null order, and the `[Order!]!` array will prevent a null element. All of this will bubble up to `ordersSearch` which can't be null, and you will get `data: null`.

So what can you do?

You can relax the non-null constraints. This schema for instance:

```
type OrdersSearch {
  name: String!
  orders: [Order]! # Elements can be null.
}
```

This will allow response of the following form. Not exactly what you want, but close enough.

```json
    "data": “ordersSearch”: [ 
      "name": “test”, 
      "orders": [
        null,
        {
          “id": “2”,
          "name": “test”
        },
        null
      ]
```

## 2. With a graphql schema redesign

When some errors are expected to happen, and when both the backend and the frontend developpers have to agree over their meaning, it makes sense to NOT use GraphQL errors. Just make errors part of the schema ! Then you get to define all the behaviour.

Such a schema could do:

```
type query {
  ordersSearch: OrdersSearch!
}
type OrdersSearch {
  name: String!
  orders: [OrderSearchResult!]!
}
type OrderSearchResult {
  found: Boolean!
  order: Order
  errorCode: OrderSearchResultErrorCode
}
type Order {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
}
enum OrderSearchResultErrorCode {
  PRODUCT_OUT_OF_STOCK
  PRODUCT_NOT_FOUND
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This solution is what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603497/4868839

Answer (score 3):

So I think I understand what you're looking for now. It sounds like the object you have exists, but you're also doing "some lookup" to see if it's "complete" or "ready" or something like that. This means you have "some data" that you can return on, and you want to tell the client when you have partial data.

### TLDR

As long as your resolver returns an array of Promises, instead of a single promise, it will work the way you're looking for.

### Problem: One Error

For this example, which returns only a single promise:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    orders: async () => {
      const orderIds = await checkForOrders();

      // Wait for all promises to resolve, and then return the single value
      const orders = await Promise.all(orderIds.map(async(orderId) => {
        return await loadOrder(orderId); // Assume this can throw
      }));
      return orders;
    },
  },
};
```

The response looks like this:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Order not found: 4adeaca9-81d5-482a-a846-2c09dabfde16",
      "path": ["orders"]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "orders": null
  }
}
```

### Solution: Array of Promises

Now if I change my resolver so that it returns an array of promises, instead of just one promise:

```js
const resolvers = {
  Query: {
    orders: async () => {
      const orderIds = await checkForOrders();

      // Return the array of promises
      return orderIds.map(async(orderId) => {
        return await loadOrder(orderId); // Assume this can throw
      });
    },
  },
};
```

The response gives you what you're looking for:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Order not found: 4adeaca9-81d5-482a-a846-2c09dabfde16",
      "path": ["orders", 1]
    },
    {
      "message": "Order not found: 8507aaf3-bfc2-46cb-bee2-358847cc632a",
      "path": ["orders", 2]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "orders": [
      {
        "id": "f18e7627-9844-4927-8441-e61f660b72fd",
        "name": "some name"
      },
      null,
      null,
      {
        "id": "8af5089c-fa87-4c37-af0b-ce3b79aea6fc",
        "name": "some other name"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Edit:

I realize it's not *quite* what you asked for, since my response has some `null` values in there where yours only had the successes, but you can really only get an error out where an object was expected (and becomes `null`).

If you really *really* want to filter out those `null` values, you could pass a function in your `formatResponse` into ApolloServer and strip it out. Just be aware that if you do that, the `path` values are no longer going to be semantically true. In my example, I threw errors on numbers 1 & 2, and if I were to strip out the `null` values, my array would only be as long as [0, 1], and [1] will have a value in it, so the `path` strings that said my entries 1 & 2 are bad could cause problems with a smart GraphQL client.

Comment: Thanks. This solution is what I was looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603497/4868839

Answer (score 0):

I wasted a lot of time on a similar thing when the gist was change my schema from

```
  items(ids: [ID!]!): [item!]!
```

to this

```
  items(ids: [ID!]!): [item]!
```

I just wanted to call out really directly that if your schema does not allow for nullable items in the array, apollo-server seems to generally throw the first error and short-circuit.

I discovered this when I attempted to just return null. I think the error that manifests in this scenario from Apollo is deceiving.

Returning an array of mixed Errors and Objects to be used to resolve fields worked for me.